# Is it possible to use https instead of http as the binding in azure

Tags: http

Is it possible to use https instead of http as the binding in azure. I don't want to pay and I'd appreciate if I got the answer.

I looked around I couldn't find anything on it.

Comment: LetsEncrypt has free SSL certs.  Browsers are getting more and more hostile to HTTP sites so unless this is just for messing around you do need HTTPS.

Comment: Your update makes the question says the opposite of the title!

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to the App Service in the Azure portal. Select the "TLS/SSL settings" option under the "Settings" section. In the "TLS/SSL settings" pane, select the "HTTP Only" option under the "HTTPS Only" section. Save the changes. After making these changes, your App Service will be accessible over HTTP instead of HTTPS. However, keep in mind that any data transmitted between the client and the server will be sent in plain text, which can be intercepted by third parties. It is highly recommended to use HTTPS instead to ensure the security of your application.